# Bootstrap tabs showing content below previous tab

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have a webform in which i am trying to implement tabs using bootstrap 4. The content for 1st tab is shown fine but when I switch tabs the content for the second tab is shown under the previous content and the tabs dont switch. Below is my code:

```
<nav class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#teacher">Teacher Remarks</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#marks">Marks</a>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="teacher" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" aria-labelledby="teacher">
        <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Content of div1
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="marks" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" aria-labelledby="marks">
        <asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                Content of div2
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help? I dont understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've marked both tabpanels as `show active`, which means they will both display by default on a page load. Try removing the `show` and `active` classes from the second div.

Edit: As per the comments below, the solution was to put the tab panel for the second tab within the first tab panel.

Comment: I tried removing ```show``` and ```active``` classes. The results are same.

Comment: should I put tab panel inside the update panel?

Comment: The tabs seem to work with your code in a code sandbox without the asp specific elements - the ContentTemplates should be fine but I might try moving stuff in or out of the UpdatePanel. Try wrapping the form in an UpdatePanel like in this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hi, the problem was within the code. I have put tab panel for second tab inside the first tab panel. I fixed that and it worked just fine.